# How do I detect when a device attached to the system is ready for use?

Tags: c#, windows-7, device, hid

I'm sorry if this is similar to an earlier question but this is something I just noticed.
I can detect when my device is attached to the system (via usb) and trap the message correctly however if I unplug and plug the device back, attempting to access the device via the [CreateFile()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363858%28VS.85%29.aspx) function always returns an error: **ERROR_GEN_FAILURE 31 (0x1F)** which translates to -**A device attached to the system is not functioning**, this is however, attempted after recieving the **DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL** message which by [microsoft's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363480%28VS.85%29.aspx) own definition says "**A device or piece of media has been inserted and is now available**". I believe what's going on here is that the error has more to do with the device not being ready even though it's reported as being ready because if I re-enumerate the list of devices on the system again, the device is ready. Has anyone else encountered and gotten past this problem? Or is there something I'm missing/overlooking?

Comment: You might want to give a clue as to what OS you are talking about - it sounds like some version of Windows, but who knows ? (Hint: tags are useful here)

Comment: Does it work as expected if you *don't* unplug and reconnect? It sounds like you're trying to work with the old reference, when really you need a new one any time the device is reattached.

Comment: @Jay You maybe onto something here. I'll look into it and repost if I solve it

Comment: @Jay Everything is fine when enumerated if plugged in. Also when I plug and unplug If I re-enumerate the list of system devices it works fine.

Comment: I don't think there's getting around it. I think the list of system devices need to be re-enumerated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to deal with this, IMO, is through WMI.

See here: http://dotnetslackers.com/community/blogs/basharkokash/archive/2008/02/06/usb-port-insert-remove-detection-using-wmi.aspx

I have used WMI in the past for USB drive detection and it is dead simple and the callback makes things pretty clean

Comment: Apologies I know nothing of WMI

Comment: Yeah, neither did I the first time I tired it. However, take a look at the article I posted. It is simple.

Comment: Sorry, but this answere isn't true. The described event only indicates that a device is attached to the system and maybe that some information could be retrieved from the device. But the question was "when it is ready to use". In my optinion this includes that the driver was succesfully started, so that I'm able to use the device. But the WMI event does not include this. E.g: I attached FTDI device and use WMI to detect when it was attached. It lasts about 5 seconds between the WMI event was fired and the time I'm actually able to open the device.

Comment: @0xBADF00D do you care to post a correct answer then? A comment saying "this is wrong" without a corrected answer isn't that helpful

Comment: @BradCunningham The problem is, I found no solution yet. I'm pretty sure that there is no possibility through WMI. At the moment I simply detect changes via WMI and then try to use the device, if it does not work, I wait and try it again. Maybe there is some way using PInvoke, but I don't know yet. With my comment I simply want to give a hint to other readers, that the given solution does'nt solve the problem completely.